# Lightkurve nan values after bin light curve

Tags: python, astropy, astronomy

I am using [lightkurve](https://docs.lightkurve.org/) 2.0.2 library with Python 3.8.5 and astropy 4.2 for processing exoplanet transits. However when I want to bin light curve to fixed number of points, all values in `light_curve.flux` except first two are nan. What I am doing wrong?

```
import lightkurve as lk

tp = lk.search_targetpixelfile("Kepler-10", mission="Kepler", exptime="long", quarter=1).download()
lc = tp.to_lightcurve().flatten().remove_outliers()
fold = lc.fold(0.837)
bin = fold.bin(n_bins=101)

print(bin.flux)  # [0.99999749 0.99999977 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan]
```

Comment: Check `time_bin_size` argument to `bin()` – you might want to tweak that. Otherwise it is fixed to 0.5 (days), and empty rows get appended to fill requested bins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, binning is done based on the time data of the `fold` variable. Let's have a look at the data:

```py
print(fold)

# =>          time                flux        ... 
#                             electron / s    ... 
#     -------------------- ------------------ ... 
#     -0.41839904743025785 0.9999366372082438 ... 
#     -0.41790346068516393 0.9999900469016064 ... 
#     -0.41710349403700253  1.000098604170269 ... 
#                      ...                ... ... 
#      0.41749621545238175 1.0000351718333538 ... 
#       0.4178061659377394 1.0000272820282354 ... 
#      0.41829640771343823 1.0000199004079346 ...
```

This means we have data from about -0.4 days to 0.4 days.

Then the binning is done using `bin = fold.bin(n_bins=101)`. Documentation about the arguments to the `bin` method (truncated):

> ```
>    time_bin_size : `~astropy.units.Quantity`, float
>        The time interval for the binned time series.
>        (Default: 0.5 days; default unit: days.)
>    time_bin_start : `~astropy.time.Time`, optional
>        The start time for the binned time series. Defaults to the first
>        time in the sampled time series.
>    n_bins : int, optional
>        The number of bins to use. Defaults to the number needed to fit all
>        the original points. Note that this will create this number of bins
>        of length ``time_bin_size`` independent of the lightkurve length.
> ```

You only pass the `n_bins` parameter. This means, the method is going to create 101 bins with a width of 0.5 starting at -0.4. So first bin from -0.4 to 0.1, second one from 0.1 to 0.6, third one from 0.6 to 1.1, ...

Now it is obvious that only the first two bins contain data.

Instead of `n_bins`, use `bins`:

> ```
>    bins : int
>        The number of bins to divide the lightkurve into. In contrast to
>        ``n_bins`` this sets the length of ``time_bin_size`` accordingly.
> ```

This is the result:

```py
bin = fold.bin(bins=101)
print(bin.flux) 

# => [1.0000268  1.00003322 1.00001914 1.00001018 1.00000905 1.00002073
#     0.99999502 1.00000155 1.0000071  0.99999901 1.000028   0.99998768
#     0.99998992 1.00003623 1.00001132 1.00005118 0.99998819 1.00001886
#     ...
#     1.00001082 1.00004898 1.0000009  1.00001234 1.00000681] electron / s
```

The `bins` parameter is not available in lightkurve 2.0.2, but in 2.0.6 (thanks @Michal).

Comment: Thank you, it works. I just had to upgrade the lightkurve to version 2.0.6, because in 2.0.2 there was no 'bins' parameter.

Comment: @Michal Sorry, I did not check versions. I was on the lightkurve homepage and they told me to `python -m pip install lightkurve --upgrade`. I add your comment to the answer.